# AttributeError on transcript results from Google Speech API

Tags: python, google-cloud-speech

1. OS type and version: `Windows 10, build 16199.1000`
2. Python version and virtual environment information `python --version`: `Python 2.7.12 (v2.7.12:d33e0cf91556, Jun 27 2016, 15:24:40) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32`
3. google-cloud-python version: `google-cloud-speech==0.27.0`

Stack Trace:

```
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\threading.py", line 754, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "E:/Programming/Python/untitled1/main.py", line 109, in get_transcript
    print('. '.join(resp.alternative.transcript for resp in res), file=sys.stderr)
  File "E:/Programming/Python/untitled1/main.py", line 109, in <genexpr>
    print('. '.join(resp.alternative.transcript for resp in res), file=sys.stderr)
AttributeError: 'SpeechRecognitionResult' object has no attribute 'alternative'
```

Steps to reproduce:

When I use this:

```
alternatives = operation.result().results[0].alternatives
    for alternative in alternatives:
        print('Transcript: {}'.format(alternative.transcript))
        print('Confidence: {}'.format(alternative.confidence))
```

It works as intended, but only prints the first transcript. When I use this:

```
res = operation.result().results
print(res, file=sys.stderr)
print('. '.join(resp.alternative.transcript for resp in res), file=sys.stderr)
```

I get the exception above. I have also tried `print('. '.join(resp.transcript for resp in res), file=sys.stderr)` and `print('. '.join(resp.alternative for resp in res), file=sys.stderr)`, just as print debugging. Both throw an `AttributeError` on either attribute.

Complete working example: https://gist.github.com/mxplusb/8f487a6ff3c781689799bb7ce1dec3f3.
It removes the audio from a video file using `ffmpeg` in the proper format, uploads it to GCS, and then performs an asynchronous speech-to-text recognition. I am trying to concatenate all the transcripts into one large text string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a slight typo as according to the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/speech/reference/rpc/google.cloud.speech.v1beta1#speechrecognitionresult) the field is `alternatives` not `alternative`.

The `alternatives` attribute is an array containing `SpeechRecognitionAlternative` objects, each with their own `transcript`, in your example you are iterating through the results, but not through each alternative; instead you are assuming only one alternative and I think that is why you chose to type out `alternative` instead of `alternatives` and iterating correctly throughout.

To fix this just change your `resp.alternative` to `resp.alternatives` and iterate correctly through every alternative printing out its transcript.

Comment: So that was it, it was a typo! I had to do a little more debugging, but that's the gist of it, thanks!